# Go - package ast : find package in file

Tags: parsing, go, package, abstract-syntax-tree

I am parsing files with the **ast package**.
I have been looking at the documentation for a bit and I can't find a way to **determine if a token is a package declaration**, *e.g*: `package main` at the beggining of the file.

```
func find_package(node ast.Node) bool {
    switch x := node.(type) {
    // This works with *ast.Ident or *ast.FuncDecl ... but not
    // with *ast.Package
    case *ast.Package:
        fmt.Print(x.Name)
    }
    return true
}
```

I am looking for a clean way to do this with the **ast package**, I am almost sure I am just missing something in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, it seems like you have to look for a `File` instead of a package:

```
func find_package(node ast.Node) bool {
    switch x := node.(type) {
    case *ast.File:
        fmt.Print(x.Name)
    }
    return true
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#File